# Don't show user name who create post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to created user-post association.I used simple scaffolding, when I create a post with the name of the user, in view "show" username is "0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".

```
rails g scaffold User name
rails g scaffold Post title body:text user:references
```

All of the code will not put, becouse I did it scaffold.There all the standard have not changed anything.

How fix?

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the information about the user, you need to edit the view templates. Go to `app/views/posts/show.html.erb` and delete the paragraph (`<p>`) mentioning the user.

```
<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @post.user %>
</p>
```

Note that to properly show the user e.g. display his/her username, you can just output the name attribute.

```
<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @post.user.name %>
</p>
```

The same applies for the `index.html.erb` template for displaying all users.